# How to make an attribute as unique magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I have installed loging advanced so i can log in with a login or an email but how to make the login unique as the email any idea please.

Comment: You can write an upgrade script to make it "Unique". Also, you can write a stored procedure to check its already exist or not.

Comment: the unique does not exist for custmer attribute as i know but how to write a procedure to check if it already exists can you give me more detials